# How to implement infinite scroll in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have lot of data which I would like to populate dynamically on scroll. I don't want to implement show hide functionality because it will increase the page loading time. The data will be defined in html format.

Eg:

```
<p>para 1</p>
<p>para 2</p>
<p>para 3</p>
...
<p>para 1000</p>
```

I looked at the `ngx-infinite-scroll` package. However in the demo they have dynamically generated the data which is different from what I need. Since I already have static data in html format.

http://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demos.html

Comment: Are you saying the HTML tags are stored in the database - or you are concatenating the data with the HTML on the fly?

Comment: No I'm not planning to use database, I want to populate data from html component.

Comment: Where is the HTML component being retrieved from? And can it be retrieved in another format ie. JSON?

Comment: The difficulty here is that there are no identifiers in the HTML code, so nothing to be able to iterate through to figure out how far you have scrolled. The only thing that is obvious is the beginning and the end of the data source.

Comment: Maybe if we add ID as an identifier for iteration? Eg: `<p id="1">para 1</p>`. We can use JSON but HTML is prefered since there would be lot of classes applied for styling purpose.

Comment: If you can change the structure of the data - I would highly recommend storing it in a structure that Angular can more natively digest, my choice would be JSON. And then take another look at the package above and how to implement that with your data.